# Inconsistent read in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm seeing inconsistent behavior, and am wondering what I could be doing wrong here.

I have `subscription` objects, whose state is defined by its `cycle` and `con` attributes, that are integers.  `months_passed` returns an integer that counts how many FULL months has passed between the `start_date` of the subscription and `Time.current`.

```
  def update_state
    update_cycle
    update_con
    self.save
  end

  def update_cycle
    self.cycle = if months_passed > 0
      (months_passed - 1)/3 + 1
    else
      0
    end
  end

  def update_con
    self.con = if months_passed > 0
      (months_passed - 1) % 3 + 1
    else
      0
    end
  end

  def in_con1?
    update_state
    con == 1
  end
```

However, when I call `in_con1?`, quickly in succession, I'll inconsistently get true or false.

Do I need to reload the object?  Is something stale?

Comment: is there some before_save callback that increments or initializes months_passed ?

Comment: Can you please explain what you expect your code to do. `cycle` and `con` tells me nothing and what is a typical input for `month_passed`?

Comment: I'll ask one more, general question - what is month_passed? If this is a method, does it depend on cycle or con?

Comment: Edited the question above.  @SteveTurczyn there is no before_save callback to increment `months_passed`.  The method is actually just doing the calculation.

Comment: What is `months_passed` definition? is it an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Argh, sorry guys.  I found the culprit.  Had nothing to do with inconsistent database reads.  It was when `months_passed` was getting called, an hour before I expected.